# How to know the parent process if the child is launched in background and the parent is already exited

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, ash

I have a child process running in foreground and his father is already exited.

the `proc/$pid/stat` file does not contain any more the parent pid if the parent is already exited and it display 1 instead of the origin parent pid

```
linux$cat /proc/6267/stat
6267 (test3.sh) S 1 6265 ......
#                 ^
#                 |
#        I expected to get the origin parent pid but I get 1
```

To reproduce this behaviour quickly we can use the following scripts

**test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "test2=$$"
./test3.sh &
```

**test3.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "test3=$$"
sleep 1000
```

execution:

```
linux$ ./test2.sh
test2=6318
test3=6319
linux$ ps aux | grep test
 6319 root      1484 S    {test3.sh} /bin/sh ./test3.sh
linux$ cat /proc/6319/stat
6319 (test3.sh) S 1 6318 2138 34816 6.......
```

Comment: Yes, orphaned processes are "adopted" by `init` (pid `1`). This is by design, and to my knowledge there is no way to recover the original parent pid once the parent process has exited.

Comment: ... and if you did kludge together a way, pids are eventually recycled, so that number might not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can know the parent of a process after the (parent) has finished executing. But maybe you can have another program running which monitors your original program and maintains a log file or something. And orphaned processes are of course, adopted by init.